# Show some images after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show some images after page load. So I try this. But it's not working. I think someone can help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("btnseemore1").click(function(){
    $("#seemore1").html("<div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/1.jpg' alt='Image 01' /></div><div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/2.jpg' alt='Image 02' /></div><div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/3.jpg' alt='Image 03' /></div><div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/4.jpg' alt='Image 04' /></div>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //btnseemore1 should be either class or id if its class then jquery will be  $(".btnseemore1").click(function(){}); and if its id than it will be  $("#btnseemore1").click(function(){});
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("btnseemore1").click(function(){
        $("#seemore1").html("<div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/1.jpg' alt='Image 01' /></div><div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/2.jpg' alt='Image 02' /></div><div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/3.jpg' alt='Image 03' /></div><div class='col-sm-3 popup-gallery'><img src='images/4.jpg' alt='Image 04' /></div>");
      });
    });
    }, 3000);
```

Use jQuery setTimeout function

Comment: It's a id. Can you tell me, what happen with setTimeout function?

Comment: settimeout is function which call your code after some times for eg. i used 3000 millisecond its means code will be call after document load + 3 sec

Comment: Can you tell me how to load few images one by one with a little fade effect

Comment: you have to refer jquery fade document http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Comment: Actually I haven't much knowledge about js and jquery. Can you write a little code snip for me. It'll be a big thing to me.

Comment: I show 4 images with page load. Now I need to show another 4 set by clicking a <a> tag with little fade effect. It'll be nice it show image one after one with little fade.

Comment: Ambition is reduce page load time. Image load from server after click on the link with this way know?

Comment: Static meant? Those are use to show gallery of works. And I apply lightbox to zoom.